# What are the differences between the exam and xsim classes?

Tags: exam, xsim

I am currently preparing exercises and wonder which class [xsim](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xsim) or [exam](https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/exam/examdoc.pdf) is best suited for the task. They seem to fulfill the same purpose, but I get the impression xsim comes with more support for randomly selecting exercises from collections, but misses some features (out-of-the-box) for exams like multiple-choice questions.

Is this correct? What are the main differences between these classes and which one is more mature for exams **and** exercises?

Comment: The same question came to my mind. A quick look will tell you that exam is more of a complete document class with slow updates (it can take three or four years to have a new stable update). On the other hand, xsim is frequently updated yet not as complete as exam for constructing a full exam (e.g. headers, footers, etc). I still prefer to stick with exam.

Comment: @Diaa xsim will probably never come with a full class. It rather encourages user to build their own class using all the loads of possibilities for customization that. Think of xsim more of a generic package that is meant for customization.

Comment: @cgnieder and that is a good thing. Thanks for building this awesome package.